How to completely disable EJB timers annotated with @Schedule?
The app has a bunch of EJB annotated with @Schedule.
Is there a way to completely disable them?
I am using Wildfly 26.
Ideally I would like to disable it using jboss-cli. Or configure via standalone.xml file.
thank you.
